# How do I use my ".selectedIndex;" value from select box as my index in my PHP request?

Tags: php, ajax, select, dojo, indexing

I have a select box  that uses "onchange" to select a value based on the users choice.

```
//AddSelect start of function
    var TownSelect = function(options){
        var _dom_element = document.createElement("select");
            _dom_element.id = 'selectMenu';

        for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
        var _option = document.createElement("option");
            _option.value = options[i];
            _option.innerHTML = options[i];
            _dom_element.appendChild(_option);

            _dom_element.onchange = function(){
            var checkValue = document.getElementById('selectMenu').selectedIndex;
                //alert(options [checkValue]);
            };
        }

        this.getDomElement = function() {
            return _dom_element;
        }
    }
    //AddSelect end of function
```

Here I have my dojo ajax function that makes a request to my PHP file using an index (ntown) which I need to = that value of my select menus selected value (hope that made sense):

```
     var _getWeatherInfo = function(ntown){
     dojo.xhrget({

         url: "PHP/weather.php?ntown=" + ntown,

         handleAs: "json",
         timeout: 5000,

         load: function(response) {
               _refreshWeatherList(response); 
         },

         error: function(error_msg, response) {
             _handleError(error_msg);
         }
     });
 }
```

My last question caused some confusion, If you need more info or something explained better pelase ask me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: BUMP, need some hep please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call _getWeatherInfo within the onchange function **as a function** !

```
_dom_element.onchange = function(){
   var checkValue = document.getElementById('selectMenu').selectedIndex;
   _getWeatherInfo(checkValue);
 };
```

Comment: you should look a little bit more into javascript basics :-)